# python how to make range include end boundary

Tags: python, python-3.x, range

I am trying to make `range` include end boundary,

```
if distance == 1:
     end_boundary = int(d + distance + distance)
else:
     end_boundary = int(d + distance + distance - 1)

for y in range(int(d - distance), end_boundary):
    # some other code
```

`d` contains `int` value, I am wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Also I want to make this code work when `d` and `distance` contains `float` values.

Comment: You can't make range include then end, but you can simply add 1 to the end.

Comment: `range(int(d - distance), end_boundary + 1)`

Comment: To deal with floats properly, forget about `range`.  Look at `numpy.linspace` instead.